# Does deleted destructor change aggregate initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, aggregate, language-lawyer, destructor, default-constructor

The code as follows

```
struct B {
    ~B() = delete;
};

B * b = new B{};
```

fails to compile in the latest MSVC with the error:

```
error C2512: 'B': no appropriate default constructor available
note: Invalid aggregate initialization
```

At the same time both GCC and Clang do not see anything wrong in the code, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/va9vcsEed

Is it right to assume just a bug in MSVC?

Overall, does the presence or deletion of the destructor change any rule of the aggregate initialization?

Comment: Neither definition of the aggregate in C++ Standards refers to the destructor. So it is a bug of the compiler.

Comment: Bug verified with the VS2022 beta - still doesn't compile - Fedor, will you file a bug report?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have reported the bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/No-default-constructor-error-in-case-of/1610913

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither definition of the notion of aggregate in C++ Standards refers to the destructor.

For example the definition of an aggregate in C++ 20 (9.4.2 Aggregates) sounds the following way

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 11) with
>
> (1.1) — no user-declared or inherited constructors (11.4.5),
>
> (1.2) — no private or protected direct non-static data members (11.9),
>
> (1.3) — no virtual functions (11.7.3), and
>
> (1.4) — no virtual, private, or protected base classes (11.7.2).

If to execute this statement  in MS VS 2019

```
std::cout << std::is_aggregate_v<B> << '\n';
```

then the output will be `1`.

On the other hand, the default constructor is defined as deleted (the C++ 20 Standard, 11.4.5.2 Default constructors) if

> (2.8) — any potentially constructed subobject has a type with a
> destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default
> constructor.

But in the provided example there is no such sub-object.

So it seems it is a compiler bug of MS VS 2019.