# Can a class be indestructible (have no destructor)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct A {
  ~A() requires(std::is_void_v<T>);
  //~A() requires(!std::is_void_v<T>) = default;
};

template struct A<int>;
```

I'd think that's impossible for a class not to have a destructor and gcc 13.2 seems to agree with me but clang 17.0 and msvc 19.38 don't and complain:

```
[clang] error: no viable destructor found for class 'A<int>'
[msvc ] error C7653: 'A<int>': failed to select a destructor for the class
```

(Adding the commented line to the code works around this issue and make all compilers happy.)

Which compilers are correct? What are the relevant quotes from the Standard?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314298/does-deleted-destructor-change-aggregate-initialization-in-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A (completed) class must always have a destructor. However, that destructor might be implicitly-declared, deleted or left undefined.

At the end of the class definition a destructor is chosen from the prospective destructors via overload resolution. If the user didn't declare any prospective destructor, then one is implicitly-declared. So there is always at least one candidate for this overload resolution. The program is ill-formed if the overload resolution fails.

So GCC is wrong and MSVC and Clang are correct. In your case there is no implicitly-declared prospective destructor, because you declared a prospective destructor manually. That single prospective destructor is not viable in overload resolution because its constraints are not satisfied. So overload resolution fails.

This is specified in (draft N4868) [[class.dtor]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.dtor#4.sentence-2).

If the selected destructor is defined as deleted, then the class still has a destructor, but it will be impossible to destroy objects of the class type, i.e. the class is also "indestructible". Any program trying to destroy such objects would be ill-formed.

Similarly, if the selected destructor is left undefined, then any attempt to destroy an object of the class type would render the program IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required) for violating the one-definition-rule.